# SOS morse code on Raspberry Pi OK LED - not working

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm following [Baking Pi](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok05.html), building a very basic operating system in ARMv6 assembly for the Raspberry Pi. We've gone from turning the OK LED on via the GPIO controller, to making it blink using the system timer, to making it blink according to a pattern represented by a bitmap stored in a `.int` value. This last solution doesn't appear to work. At first I thought I must have solved the problem incorrectly, but no matter how much I check my solution with the functional solution [provided here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/downloads/ok05.tar.gz), I can't see a significant difference.

I caved and finally downloaded the actual solution, compiled it and installed it on my Pi. It exhibits the same broken behaviour as my own solution. That is, the LED turns on, but just stays on. I assume the program has crashed, or the `and` instruction isn't doing what the tutor wants it to do.

The solution like like this:

```
bitmap   .req r4
seq      .req r5
ldr bitmap,=pattern
ldr bitmap,[bitmap]
mov seq,#0         /* start at the zeroth bit */

loop$:
  mov r0,#16       /* set gpio pin 16: OK LED */
  mov r1,#1        /* bitmask starts with a 1 */
  lsl r1,seq       /* shift to the correct bit */
  and r1,bitmap    /* mask according to the pattern */
  bl SetGpio       /* set the LED state (r1 zero = off, non-zero = on) */
  bl Wait          /* wait for a short interval */
  add seq,#1       /* increment the sequence counter */
  and seq,#0b11111 /* reset seq to 0 if >= 32 */
  b loop$          /* loop forever */

.section .data

.align 2
pattern:
  .int 0b11111111101010100010001000101010
```

Now I know the `Wait` and `SetGpio` functions work correctly, since the previous lesson just blinked the LED on and off at set intervals, which I was doing by `EOR`'ing a 1 or 0 with 1 on each iteration of `loop$`. The only new significant concept introduced here is the bitmap to represent the SOS pattern. I'm comfortable with bitmaps and bitmasks, as I use them regularly in higher level languages, so I think the logic is ok, but there's something else amiss, maybe with how the `.int` is being stored/padded?

Does anything jump out as being wrong with the above logic? The contract of `SetGpio` is:

- r0 must be set to the GPIO pin number, in this case 16
- r1 must be set to non-zero if the LED should be on, else zero to turn it off
- the return value is not significant

The `Wait` function looks like this:

```
/* Sleep for 500 milliseconds */
Wait:
  push {lr}
  ldr r0,=500
  bl SleepForDelay
  pop {pc}
```

EDIT | Actually, the beavhiour in both mine and the tutor's solution is:

1. LED comes on for a brief interval (a dot, I guess)
2. LED goes back off again
3. LED comes on and stays on forever

I actually thought the first blink was just the bootloader operating, but if I introduce a deliberate crash early in my program, the LED never comes on at all.

Comment: does your Wait function need an argument? in r0?

Comment: @dwelch not directly. It calls another function that does, however, but it sets it itself.

Comment: Added the Wait implementation to the question.

Comment: Updated with an EDIT, since it looks like the LED blinks twice before the crash happens, which probably helps narrow this down.

Comment: Did you setup the stack?  Try `wait: ldr r0,=500\n b SleepForDelay`.

Comment: @artlessnoise what do you mean by "setup the stack"? I have set the stack pointer to allow 8KB of space and I'm pushing `lr` onto the stack.

Comment: That is what I mean by *setup the stack*.  If you don't allocate space and set `sp`, then the `push lr` may have caused an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this had nothing to do with the code and was actually a configuration setting on the Raspberry Pi.

/config.txt needed `kernel_old=1`.